# Do Rails5 API mode app and non API mode app share codes each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm goint to create a RESTfull service app is made of Rails5 with API mode.
I also need an admin app that provides web views for managing users and contents.
These two apps will share codes each other.

I know a way of creating the API mode app.

```
$ rails new apiapp --api
```

How do I create the other project?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would implement this kind of functionality is like so:

- RAIL API for your model, database, validation and relationships logic.
- Client side MVC for Admin app with RESTful calls. For this I would use Backbone Marionette.

this is the cleanest, least code repetition implementation I can think of, which follows industry standards.

this is as per the software mantra 'consume your own dog food' - if you create an api, use its interface to do your stuff. this way you test and improve it as you go.

If you want RAILS only on both ends, you would be better off implementing your ADMIN and your API as one app, for least code repetition. Create an API controller name space for all your exterior calls, and code normal rails for your admin views and stuff. this way your database and model validation and relationship logic is shared, but controllers and route namespaces are not.

Toodles.

Answer (score 0):

You build the other project as a normal rails project.  The thing to understand about Rails 5 api mode is that you cannot have normal html stuff as part of it.  The entire rendering pipeline (assets and such) is missing.  Rails 5 api mode is fast because big parts of the environment are just plain gone.

What you want to do is have 2 projects:

- admin
- api

And figure out a way to share your model logic across them.

If you use devise for authentication this is particularly tricky since devise adds things into your user model that you cannot have in an api project.  Here's how I got around it:

```rb
If Rails.application.class.parent_name == "admin"
  # devise crap goes here
end
```

How exactly you easily share a directory of models across 2 git repos?  I have no good answer.  I have a rake task which sync's things manually by copying them from the canonical source to the destination but that's a hack.